# Android - GetView() in Custom GridAdapter

Tags: android, xml, gridview, fragment, adapter

I'm working on a new app (first big project) and I'm facing an issue with custom view adapter for GridView and after 2 hours of seeking answer in web I still cannot resolve it.

The goal is to dynamically put Buttons into GridLayout while a Fragment is being created, before I show my code I would like to say that I'm very new in Fragments and Android itself so I might missed something silly.

The problem is that it is displaying only 2 random buttons from an Array of strings passed to the constructor, I tried to debug and the problem seems to be in getView() method.

Fragment onCreateView:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutor_signup_step_one, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    // professions
    addProfeesions(professionsList);

    gridViewButtonAdapter = new GridViewButtonAdapter(getContext(), professions);

    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewButtonAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

public void addProfeesions(String[] profession_list) {

    professions.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < profession_list.length; i++) {

        professions.add(profession_list[i]);
    }
}
```

Fragment XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tutorSignupLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.SignupStepOneActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/signup_step_one_under_welcome"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.123"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additionalInfoTextView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Choose your profession" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

        </GridView>


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

My custom ViewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<String> list;
private Context context;

public GridViewButtonAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {

    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, viewGroup, false);

    } else {

        LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.gridLinear);
        linearLayout.addView(addButton(list.get(i)));
    }

    return view;
}

private Button addButton(String text) {

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button button = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button, null);

    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setText(text);
    Log.i("INFO BUTTON", text);
    return button;

}
```

row_grid.XML (used to fill GridLayout cell)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/gridLinear"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">


 </LinearLayout>
```

I will be very greatful for any help with this, will keep troubleshooting in the meantime, thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish, exactly. Why are you adding `Button`s to the `GridView` items separately? That is, why isn't the `Button` in `row_grid` to begin with? How many `Button`s per profession do you ultimately need?

Comment: You are right, I was doing it wrong from the beginning, problem is already solved and I will post working code later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as stated above I have resolved the issue with missing buttons but now I can't figure out how to remove spaces between items in gridView.

In other words, how can I make a cell to wrap its content?

GridVew:

```
        <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3" >

    </GridView>
```

row_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearTest"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
    style="@style/My.Button.One"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_1"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Bart